# Ensemble Empirical Mode decomposition

Tags: r, rstudio

I have tried to use the EEMD on a certain xts object data and have gotten the next reply:

```
Error in `/.difftime`(diff(unphase, lag), diff(tt, lag)) : 
  second argument of / cannot be a "difftime" object
```

I am writing to you because I have no clue what might be wrong and have searched the www for answers, but couldn't find any. My code while using this was

```
load("C:/Users/Domen/Desktop/SnP_close.Rdata")
here <- EEMD(sig=as.numeric(Snp[,1]),tt=time(Snp[,1]),noise.amp=100,trials=100,nimf=6,trials.dir="trials")
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `Error in`/.difftime`(diff(unphase, lag), diff(tt, lag))`  is telling you that the "/" function for the 'difftime' class (since S3 function dispatch is determined by the first argument) cannot be divided by a value that is also a 'difftime'. I've sometimes been annoyed at the limitations of operations on 'difftime' objects, myself. I usually end up converting to numeric as you started to do, but probably need to go a bit further. Perhaps:

```
here <- EEMD( sig=as.numeric(Snp[,1]), tt=as.numeric( time(Snp[,1] ) ), 
               noise.amp=100,trials=100,nimf=6,trials.dir="trials")
```

Without a concrete example this is just a guess. The 'tt' variable in the argument list *might* be the same as the argument that was throwing the error. (Or it might not. It depends on how the functions define their variables internally.) It appears you are using not just the 'xts' package but also another package that has a `time` function, as well as the unnamed package that has `EEMD`. You should name all the package needed and include a specific data object with `dput`.